# the react-native-maps callout onPress triggerin a Modal is not working with google map on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

Using react-native-maps with `PROVIDER_GOOGLE` on iOS, there is a problem when clicking on the callout to popup a modal from there.
It's working fine on apple map or on android.
But with google provider, after I click on the marker to popup the callout, I have to click again on the marker to open the modal.
In the following code, if I click on the callout it gives the alert in the function in the onPress but not the modal. If I want the modal, you have to press on the marker again once the callout is open.
Would it be because of something that iOS doesn't like in the style ?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Alert, Modal } from "react-native";
import MapView, { Marker, Callout, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps";

const MapBar = ({ coords }) => {
    const [modalVisible, setModal] = useState(false);
    const handleModal = (isModalActive) => {
        setModal(isModalActive);
    }
    const calloutPress = () => {
        setModal(true);
        Alert.alert("Clicking on the callout");

    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
            <MapView
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                style={styles.map}
                rotateEnabled={false}
                mapType="standard"
                initialRegion={region}
            >
                <Marker
                    coordinate={markerCoordinate}
                    onCalloutPress={() => calloutPress()}
                >
                    <Callout onPress={() => calloutPress()}>
                        <Modal
                            animationType="slide"
                            transparent={true}
                            presentationStyle="pageSheet"
                            visible={modalVisible}
                            onRequestClose={() => {
                                setModal(false);
                            }}
                            onDismiss={() => setModal(false)}
                        >
                            <View style={styles.centeredView}>

                                <View style={styles.modalView}>
                                    <Text style={styles.modalType}></Text>
                                    <Text>fezrferger</Text>
                                    <Text>fezrferger</Text>
                                    <Text>fezrferger</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </Modal>
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.calloutTitle}>My title</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.calloutDescription}>My description</Text>
                        </View>
                    </Callout>
                </Marker>
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );


}

const region = {
    latitude: 50.846592,
    longitude: 4.352455,
    latitudeDelta: 0.05,
    longitudeDelta: 0.05
};

const markerCoordinate = { latitude: 50.846592, longitude: 4.352455 };

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mapContainer: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        zIndex: 0
    },
    map: {
        flex: 1
    },
    calloutTitle: {
        fontSize: 17,
        marginBottom: 5,
        fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    calloutDescription: {
        fontSize: 14
    },
    centeredView: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: 22,

    },
    modalView: {
        width: '95%',
        margin: 20,
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderRadius: 20,
        padding: 35,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 2
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 4,
        elevation: 5,
        color: "#777777"
    },
    modalText: {
        marginBottom: 15,
        textAlign: "center",
        color: "#777777"
    }
});

export default MapBar;
```